# Method filter for Surefire

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

From this page:
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

under "Fully qualified class name" section, It seems possible to specify which test methods to run in **pom.xml**. However, it is not very clear where to write this tag called "test". Anyone could shed some lights?

Comment: it might be worthwhile to point out this feature is supported on JUnit 4.x, not JUnit 3.x. and how to enable it is illustrated by Ahmed Ashour below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

You can define it inside `<properties>`, as in:

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <test>TestCircle#testSlow</test>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Also, you can use `includes` and `excludes` as hinted [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html), e.g.:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>Sample.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

and

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/TestCircle.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/TestSquare.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed Ashour, but this is not what I expect. I want to run specific test case inside the suite, e.g. TestCircle.java#testSlow, that is why I am looking at the test tag